# Empty comment block in HTML - what's it for?

Tags: html

On a (fairly old) site I'm doing some work on currently, I've come across the following curious bit of HTML:

```
<span class="backImage" id="backImage"><!----></span>
```

There are loads of other empty comments like this on the page, so I'm assuming that they're  a hack rather than simply a mistake by the original developer. But there's no actual comment documenting their purpose, and after a bit of Googling, I can't puzzle out what it could possibly be for.

Is there perhaps some ancient version of IE in which this empty comment block affects the rendering of the parent element in some way?

Comment: You are just overcautious, I think, there is nothing.

Comment: if there are alot, then he/she created the code with some tool where empty elements have comments to let user know that something has to be written. I dont understand what would be a possible hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty comment has the same meaning as any comment, namely no meaning (to software processing HTML). Although it is imaginable that some ancient browser had a bug that made an empty comment have some effect, the odds are that `<!---->` between the start tag and the end tag of an element is just a comment, to people who might read the markup. It would then say just that the content of the element is intentionally left empty.

Comment: Alternatively, it might have been the product of code generation by, for example, a CMS or a WYSIWIG editor, as suggested by Rob Nawas.

Answer (score 4):

Empty comments can be used as a workaround for removing whitespace between inline-block elements. See http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ for details.

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li><!--
  --><li>two</li><!--
  --><li>three</li>
</ul>
```